# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am getting following exception,please help to resolve this ?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.UserDAO com.controller.UserController.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.UserDAO com.controller.UserController.userDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dao.UserDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:609)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Respective java codes are as below -
**UserDAO**

```
package com.dao;
import java.util.List;
import com.entity.UserDetails;
public interface UserDAO {
    public List<UserDetails> getUserProfileDetails();
    public int saveUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails);
    public UserDetails authenticateUser(String email,String password);
    public void closeSessionObjects();
}
```

**UserDAOImpl**

```
package com.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dao.UserDAO;
import com.entity.UserDetails;


@Component
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDAOImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    Session session = null;
    private void assignSessionLocalVariable(){
        if(session == null || !session.isOpen()){
            try{                
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            }catch(Exception e){session = null;}
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDetails> getUserProfileDetails() {
        List<UserDetails> details=null;
        if(session!=null){
            try{
                    Query query = session.createQuery("from user");
                    details = query.list();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                logger.error("########### Exception occured ########## "+e+" ");
            }
        }
        return details;
    }
    @Override
    public int saveUserDetails(UserDetails userDetails){
        int saved=1;
        assignSessionLocalVariable();
        try{
                Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
                session.save(userDetails);
                tx.commit();
                saved=0;
                logger.info("#### Details saved successfuly #####");
        }catch(Exception e){
                logger.error("### Exception occured in UserDAOImpl class #### "+e+"");
        }
        return saved;
    }


    @Override
    public UserDetails authenticateUser(String email, String pwd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("##### UserDAOImple authenticateuser started #####");
        assignSessionLocalVariable();
        logger.info("### Authentication of the user in progress ####");
        UserDetails users = null;
        if(session!=null){
            try{
                Query qry = session.createQuery ("from user hu where hu.email = :email and hu.password = :password");
                qry.setParameter ("email", email);
                qry.setParameter ("password", pwd);
                qry.setMaxResults(1);
                users = (UserDetails)qry.uniqueResult();
            }catch(Exception e){
                users = null;
                System.out.println("UserDAOImpl exception in getting unique result["+e+"] ");
                logger.error("UserDAOImpl exception in getting unique result["+e+"]");
            }           
        }//if(session!=null)
        return users;       
    }

    public void closeSessionObjects(){
        if(null != session) session.clear();//close();
        //if(null != sessionFactory) sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

**UsedDetails.java**

```
package com.entity;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="user",catalog="test")
public class UserDetails implements java.io.Serializable{

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private Date creationTime;
    private Date lastModTime;
    private String password;
    private String email;


    public UserDetails(){}

    public  UserDetails(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="ID", unique = true, nullable = false) 
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name="AGE")
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "CREATION_TIME", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }
    public void setCreationTime(Date creationTime) {
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "LAST_MOD_TIME", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getLastModTime() {
        return lastModTime;
    }
    public void setLastModTime(Date lastModTime) {
        this.lastModTime = lastModTime;
    }

    @Column(name="PASSWORD")
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
package com.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.dao.UserDAO;
import com.entity.UserDetails;


@Controller
public class UserController {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserController.class);
    String errForward = "user.error", forward = null;

   @Autowired
   UserDAO userDAO;

   @Autowired
   UserDetails ud=null;;

   @RequestMapping("/register")
   public ModelAndView registerPage() {
       logger.info("## Registration page forward #####");
       return new ModelAndView("user.registration");

   }

   @RequestMapping("/registerUser")
   public ModelAndView registerUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
       logger.info("### Inside registeration controller  ####");
           int isSave=0;
           Date creation_time=null,lastModTime=null;
           String fName=request.getParameter("fName");
           fName=(fName.equals(""))?"":fName.trim();
           String lName=request.getParameter("lName");
           lName=(lName.equals(""))?"":lName.trim();
           int age=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
           age=(age==0)?0:age;
           String email=request.getParameter("email");
           email=(email.equals(""))?"":email.trim();
           String pswd=request.getParameter("pswd");
           pswd=(pswd.equals(""))?"":pswd.trim();

           Date date=new Date();
           //creation_time=dt.getDate();

           ud.setFirstName(fName);
           ud.setLastName(lName);
           ud.setAge(age);
           ud.setPassword(pswd);
           ud.setEmail(email);
           ud.setCreationTime(creation_time);
           ud.setLastModTime(lastModTime);
           try{
               isSave=userDAO.saveUserDetails(ud);
               if (isSave==0){ 
                   System.out.println("%%% Successfully saved the user ::::"+isSave);
                   logger.info("Successfully saved the data :::"+isSave);
                   forward="user.registrationUserSuccess";
               }
           }catch(Exception e){
               logger.error("##### Error while saving use details #####"+e);
               return new ModelAndView(forward);
           }

        return new ModelAndView(forward);
   }

       @RequestMapping("/login")
       public ModelAndView addStudent(HttpServletRequest request) {
           logger.info("### Login in  progress  ####");
           String email=request.getParameter("email");
           email=(email.equals(""))?"":email.trim();
           String pswd=request.getParameter("pswd");
           pswd=(pswd.equals(""))?"":pswd.trim();
           String login=request.getParameter("login");
            login = (null != login)?login:"";

           logger.info("### User login for ::: ["+email+"]:::: ######");
           HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
            if(null!=login)ud= userDAO.authenticateUser(email, pswd);
            if(null!=ud){
                httpSession.setAttribute("isActiveUser", ud);
                forward = "user.profile";
            }else forward = errForward;

           return new ModelAndView(forward);
       }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
  <display-name>Spring User</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
           org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>User</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>       
        <welcome-file>/jsp/home.jsp</welcome-file>       
    </welcome-file-list>   
    <session-config>         
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>     
    </session-config> 
</web-app>
```

**User-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


   <mvc:annotation-driven/> 
   <context:annotation-config/>
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.dao" />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.entity" />

   <!-- title defining -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- defining title file location -->
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <import resource="db-config.xml" /> 
</beans>
```

**db-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
    <bean id="dbPropertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/configuration.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Database Properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${jdbc.driver.className}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${jdbc.password}"               
                />
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.entity" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

When I try to run this code I am getting exception that I have posted. Autowired injection is not happening. What is the problem ?

Comment: Remove your `tiles.xml` as it's not at all related to this exception and yes you are missing to define `SessionFactory` bean in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at the Exception, It says
`nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.`

It looks like you are not creating `sessionFactory` bean. Make sure you have sessionFactory added in you spring configuration

For Example :

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
     p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
     p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
/>
```